# How to open page in browser from html file on disk with user default webrowser? (not IE)

Tags: python, html, file, web, internet-explorer

I used

```
webbrowser.open('file://page/index.html')
```

and page was opened with IE. How can i change this to user webbrowser, e.g. chrome, opera and each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webbrowser.open()` should call the default webbrowser, whatever it may be.

If you want a specific other browser,  you can use `register()` to register it, and then call `open()` in combination with `get()`, e.g.

```
webbrowser.register('chrome',
    None,
    webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))

webbrowser.get('chrome').open('file://page/index.html')
```